# Sync Embedded YouTube Video Time Stamp to Custom Progress Bar

Tags: html, css, youtube, timestamp, embed

I am stuck on a portion of a project I have been working on today. The task is to sync the timestamp information from the embedded youtube video and display a custom progress bar matching the length of the song at the bottom of the page. Here is the layout so far:

[image: Progress Bar]

So basically, how do I pull constant timestamps to update the progress and how do I animate the bar to complete 100% matching the end of the video.

I have already disabled the user's ability to scrobble the embedded youtube video. NOTE: the user should not be able to change the time of the youtube video using the custom progress bar either (it is just there for visual queue)!

Please let me know if you need more clarification. HTML and CSS are below. Thank you!! :)

HTML >>>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Chat</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
            </head>

            <body>

                <div class="header-bar">
                    <div class="bar"></div>
                    <div class="dropshadow"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="container-middle-third">
                    <div class="youtube-video" style="float: left;">
                        <div class="DJ-text">Affinity FM DJ Room</div>
                        <div class="DJ-underline"></div>
                        <div class="transparent-layer"> <iframe width="850px" height="477px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2GvIq2SpVFM?autoplay=0&showinfo=0&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>


                    </div>

                    <div class="chat" style="float: left;">
                        <div class="Chat-text">Chat</div>
                        <div class="Chat-underline"></div>
                        <input type="text" class="chat-name" placeholder="Chat">
                        <div class="info-rect">Info</div>
                        <div class="chat-messages"></div>
                        <textarea placeholder="Join the conversation..."></textarea>
                        <div class="chat-status">Status: <span>Idle</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="bottom-bar">

                    <div class="thumbnail" style="float: left"></div>
                    <div class="title-bar" style="float: left;">

                    <div class="song-name">Finding Hope - Let Go (feat. Deverano)</div>
                    <div class="dj-playing">Affinity FM is playing</div>

                    <div class="progress-background"></div>
                    <div class="progress-bar"></div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="subscribe" style="float: left;"></div>

                </div>

                <script src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

                <script>
                    (function() {
                        var getNode = function(s) {
                            return document.querySelector(s);
                        },

                        // Get required nodes
                        status = getNode('.chat-status span'),
                        messages = getNode('.chat-messages'), 
                        textarea = getNode('.chat textarea'),
                        chatName = getNode('.chat-name'),

                        statusDefault = status.textContent,    

                        setStatus = function(s){
                            status.textContent = s;

                            if(s !== statusDefault){
                                var delay = setTimeout(function(){
                                    setStatus(statusDefault);
                                    clearInterval(delay);
                                }, 3000);
                            }
                        };

                        //try connection
                        try{
                           var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080');
                        } catch(e){
                            //Set status to warn user
                        }

                        if(socket !== undefined){

                            //Listen for output
                            socket.on('output', function(data){
                                if(data.length){
                                    //Loop through results
                                    for(var x = 0; x < data.length; x = x + 1){
                                        var message = document.createElement('div');
                                        message.setAttribute('class', 'chat-message');
                                        message.textContent = ': ' + data[x].message;
                                        var name=document.createElement('span');
                                        name.setAttribute('class', 'userName');
                                        name.textContent = data[x].name;

                                        message.insertBefore(name, message.firstChild);

                                        //Append
                                        messages.appendChild(message);
                                        messages.insertBefore(message, messages.firstChild);
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                            //Listen for a status
                            socket.on('status', function(data){
                                setStatus((typeof data === 'object') ? data.message : data);

                                if(data.clear === true){
                                    textarea.value = '';
                                }
                            });

                            //Listen for keydown
                            textarea.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
                                var self = this,
                                    name = chatName.value;

                                if(event.which === 13 && event.shiftKey === false){
                                    socket.emit('input', {
                                        name: name,
                                        message: self.value
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    })();
                </script>
            </body>
        </html>
```

and CSS >>>

```
      body {
                background-color: #0f0f17;
                margin: 0px;
                width: 100%;
            }

.container-middle-third{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 155px;
}

            body,
            textarea,
            input {
                font: 13px "Raleway", sans-serif;
                color: #ffffff;

            }

            .bar{
                height: 80px;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: #15151d;   
            }

            .DJ-text{
                font-weight: 700;
                /*position:relative;*/
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }

            .Chat-text{
                font-weight: 700;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }

            .DJ-underline{
                width: 850px;
                height: 1px;
                position:relative;top:10px;
                background-color: #3f3f45;
                margin: 0px 0px 40px;
            }

            .Chat-underline{
                width: 100%;
                position:relative;
                /*left:-140px;*/
                float:right;
                height: 1px;
                position:relative;top:10px;
                background-color: #3f3f45;
                margin: 0px 0px 40px;
            }
            .transparent-layer{
                width: 850px;
                height: 477px;
                pointer-events: none;
                background-color: #ffffff;
            }

            .ad{
                width: 728px;
                height: 90px;
                border: 1px solid #000000;
                margin-left: 11px;
                margin-top: 20px;
            }

            .chat {
                min-width: 400px;
                margin: 0px 0px 0px 135px;
            }
            .chat-messages,
            .chat-textarea,
            .chat-name {
                border: 1px solid #1a1a23;
                background-color: #1a1a23;
            }

            .userName{
                font-weight: 700;
                color: #079ce0;
            }

            .chat-messages {
                width:380px;
                height:400px;
                overflow-y:scroll;
                padding:10px;
            }

            .chat-message {
                margin-bottom:10px;
            }

            .info-rect{
                height: 40px;
                width: 180px;
                padding:10px;
                max-width: 100%;
                margin:0;
                border:0;
                display: flex; 
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;  
                font-weight: 700;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                background-color: #15151d
            }

            .chat-name{
                height: 40px;
                max-width: 100%;
                width: 180px;
                padding:10px;
                border:0;
                margin:0;
                font-weight: 700;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                float:left;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .chat textarea {
                width:380px;
                padding:10px;
                margin:0;
                border-top:0;
                max-width:100%;
                border-top: 1px solid #0f0f17;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #1a1a23;
                border-right: 1px solid #1a1a23;
                border-left: 1px solid #1a1a23;
                background-color: #1a1a23;

            }

            .chat-status {
                color: #bbb;
                opacity: 0;
                background-color: #0f0f17;
            }

            .info-rect,
            .chat textarea,
            .chat-name { 
                max-width: 100%; 
            }


            .bottom-bar{
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .thumbnail{
                width: 80px;
                height: 80px;
                background-color: #ffffff
            }   

            .title-bar{
                width:1000px;
                height: 80px;
                background-color: #1a1a23;
            }
            .song-name{
                font-weight: 700;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                margin-left: 30px;
                margin-top: 25px;
            }
            .dj-playing{
                margin-left: 30px;
            }
            .progress-background{
                width: 1000px;
                height: 4px;
                background-color: #313139;
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
            }
            .progress-bar{
                width: 400px;
                height: 4px;
                background-color: #fa1d57;
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
            }
            .subscribe{
                width: 520px;
                height: 80px;
                background-color: #15151d;
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Love your questions!

1. switch the iframe with a div with `id="player"` (any name you want, it could be "my_own_player" or "XYZ_player"...)
   Then now you're all set to convert your iframe player into a Youtube player object so that you can accomplish what you desire, using the "IFrame player API".
2. Make sure you style your div the same way you wanted your iframe.
3. Just add the following script :

   ```
   //This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
   function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
   {
       player = new YT.Player("player",
       {
           height: "850",
           width: "477",
           videoId: "2GvIq2SpVFM",
           events:
           {
               "onReady": onPlayerReady,
               "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
           }
       });
   }
   ```
4. Replace `videoId` with your video's ID.
5. Replace `height` with your video's height.
6. Replace `width` with your video's width.

NOW, to get the **"Video Time Stamps"** like you say, in order to make the progress bar is easy. The player object has two methods that will do that:

- getCurrentTime()
- getDuration()

`getDuration` is the total time of the video in seconds. While `getCurrentTime` is the time where the video has played up to. Divide 
`getCurrentTime` by `getDuration` and you'll get a ratio for the progress bar. Multiply it by 100 and you get the percentage you're looking for:

```
(player.getCurrentTime()/player.getDuration())*100;
```

That's it! Once you got a percentage that represents **getCurrentTime** / **getDuration**, you don't need anything else for an html progress bar. Just style that html bar element's width to that percentage. Just make sure that red "bar" has a background (another div) that's easily recognized as the outward limit for the progress bar. Or just put it inside another div that's visible on the page like so :

```
<div id="progress" style="width: 800px; height: 10px; border: 1px solid #fff;">
    <div id="bar" style="width: 1px; height: 10px; background: #f00;"></div>
</div>
```

Please, just try out your modified HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chat</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="header-bar">
      <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="dropshadow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-middle-third">
      <div class="youtube-video" style="float: left;">
        <div class="DJ-text">Affinity FM DJ Room</div>
        <div class="DJ-underline"></div>
        <div class="transparent-layer"> <div id="player" style="width: 850px; height: 477px;"></div></div>


      </div>

      <div class="chat" style="float: left;">
        <div class="Chat-text">Chat</div>
        <div class="Chat-underline"></div>
        <input type="text" class="chat-name" placeholder="Chat">
        <div class="info-rect">Info</div>
        <div class="chat-messages"></div>
        <textarea placeholder="Join the conversation..."></textarea>
        <div class="chat-status">Status: <span>Idle</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom-bar">

      <div class="thumbnail" style="float: left"></div>
      <div class="title-bar" style="float: left;">

        <div class="song-name">Finding Hope - Let Go (feat. Deverano)</div>
        <div class="dj-playing">Affinity FM is playing</div>

        <div class="progress-background">
          <div id="progress-bar" class="progress-bar"></div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="subscribe" style="float: left;"></div>

    </div>

    <script src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

    <script>
      (function() {
        var getNode = function(s) {
          return document.querySelector(s);
        },

            // Get required nodes
            status = getNode('.chat-status span'),
            messages = getNode('.chat-messages'), 
            textarea = getNode('.chat textarea'),
            chatName = getNode('.chat-name'),

            statusDefault = status.textContent,    

            setStatus = function(s){
              status.textContent = s;

              if(s !== statusDefault){
                var delay = setTimeout(function(){
                  setStatus(statusDefault);
                  clearInterval(delay);
                }, 3000);
              }
            };

        //try connection
        try{
          var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080');
        } catch(e){
          //Set status to warn user
        }

        if(socket !== undefined){

          //Listen for output
          socket.on('output', function(data){
            if(data.length){
              //Loop through results
              for(var x = 0; x < data.length; x = x + 1){
                var message = document.createElement('div');
                message.setAttribute('class', 'chat-message');
                message.textContent = ': ' + data[x].message;
                var name=document.createElement('span');
                name.setAttribute('class', 'userName');
                name.textContent = data[x].name;

                message.insertBefore(name, message.firstChild);

                //Append
                messages.appendChild(message);
                messages.insertBefore(message, messages.firstChild);
              }
            }
          });

          //Listen for a status
          socket.on('status', function(data){
            setStatus((typeof data === 'object') ? data.message : data);

            if(data.clear === true){
              textarea.value = '';
            }
          });

          //Listen for keydown
          textarea.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
            var self = this,
                name = chatName.value;

            if(event.which === 13 && event.shiftKey === false){
              socket.emit('input', {
                name: name,
                message: self.value
              });
            }
          });
        }

      })();
    </script>
    <script>
      var time_total;
      var timeout_setter;
      var player;
      var tag = document.createElement("script");//This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      //This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player) OR uses the iframe if it exists at the "player" element after the API code downloads
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
      {
        player = new YT.Player("player",
                               {
          height: "850",
          width: "477",
          videoId: "2GvIq2SpVFM",
          events:
          {
            "onReady": onPlayerReady,
            "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }
      //The API will call this function when the video player is ready
      function onPlayerReady(event)
      {
        event.target.playVideo();
        time_total  = convert_to_mins_and_secs(player.getDuration(), 1);
        loopy();
      }

      function loopy()
      {
        var current_time = convert_to_mins_and_secs(player.getCurrentTime(), 0);
        document.getElementById("progress-bar").style.width = (player.getCurrentTime()/player.getDuration())*100+"%";
        console.log( current_time + " / " + time_total);
        timeout_setter = setTimeout(loopy, 1000);
      }

      function convert_to_mins_and_secs(seconds, minus1)
      {
        var mins    = (seconds>=60) ?Math.round(seconds/60):0;
        var secs    = (seconds%60!=0) ?Math.round(seconds%60):0;
        var secs    = (minus1==true) ?(secs-1):secs; //Youtube always displays 1 sec less than its duration time!!! Then we have to set minus1 flag to true for converting player.getDuration()
        var time    = mins + ":" + ((secs<10)?"0"+secs:secs);
        return time;
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes
      function onPlayerStateChange(event)
      {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED)
        {
          console.log("END!");
          clearTimeout(timeout_setter);
        }
        else
        {
          console.log(event.data);
        }
      }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**With your CSS:**

```css
body {
  background-color: #0f0f17;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container-middle-third{
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 155px;
}

body,
textarea,
input {
  font: 13px "Raleway", sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;

}

.bar{
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #15151d;   
}

.DJ-text{
  font-weight: 700;
  /*position:relative;*/
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.Chat-text{
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.DJ-underline{
  width: 850px;
  height: 1px;
  position:relative;top:10px;
  background-color: #3f3f45;
  margin: 0px 0px 40px;
}

.Chat-underline{
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
  /*left:-140px;*/
  float:right;
  height: 1px;
  position:relative;top:10px;
  background-color: #3f3f45;
  margin: 0px 0px 40px;
}
.transparent-layer{
  width: 850px;
  height: 477px;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.ad{
  width: 728px;
  height: 90px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  margin-left: 11px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.chat {
  min-width: 400px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 135px;
}
.chat-messages,
.chat-textarea,
.chat-name {
  border: 1px solid #1a1a23;
  background-color: #1a1a23;
}

.userName{
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #079ce0;
}

.chat-messages {
  width:380px;
  height:400px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  padding:10px;
}

.chat-message {
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.info-rect{
  height: 40px;
  width: 180px;
  padding:10px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin:0;
  border:0;
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;  
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #15151d
}

.chat-name{
  height: 40px;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 180px;
  padding:10px;
  border:0;
  margin:0;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float:left;
  text-align: center;
}

.chat textarea {
  width:380px;
  padding:10px;
  margin:0;
  border-top:0;
  max-width:100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #0f0f17;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1a1a23;
  border-right: 1px solid #1a1a23;
  border-left: 1px solid #1a1a23;
  background-color: #1a1a23;

}

.chat-status {
  color: #bbb;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #0f0f17;
}

.info-rect,
.chat textarea,
.chat-name { 
  max-width: 100%; 
}


.bottom-bar{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.thumbnail{
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #ffffff
}   

.title-bar{
  width:1000px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #1a1a23;
}
.song-name{
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.dj-playing{
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.progress-background{
  width: 1000px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #313139;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
.progress-bar{
  width: 400px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #fa1d57;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
.subscribe{
  width: 520px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #15151d;
}
```

Or just look at the result there :
http://lespointscom.com/a/misc/demo/2016_06_19/main.html

**IFrame player API reference:** 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your help, you are honestly making learning HTML/CSS an enjoyable experience. I really REALLY appreciate it! OK, so you code ALMOST works, the only issue is that the progress bar continues after its limiting point (continues to the edge of the page). You mention about this briefly in your write up about how it should be inside a layer that marks the limit....which I think has been done. Also, how would I go about making the progress bar move a bit smoother instead of in "chunks"?

Comment: It's easy :

Take out `position: fixed;` in the `.progress-bar` style

That takes care of the first mistake.

Look :  http://lespointscom.com/a/misc/demo/2016_06_19/main1.html

Comment: For the second thing you want, the best thing is to ease the transformation in the style :

`transition: all 1s linear;`

That line tells the browser to "transition" all styles change for the ellement.
That's all you need to stop it from being choppy! Just one line.


Look at : http://lespointscom.com/a/misc/demo/2016_06_19/main2.html